# How can I save two models at the same time in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know how can I save two models which has one relationship in my models. I don't know how to save it but I need the ID for my patient model to assign to my scale model.

Here is my PatientController.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'birth' => 'required',
        'nacionality' => 'required',
        'adress' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'living_method' => 'required',
        'responsable' => 'required',
    ]);

    //Create Patient
    $patient = new Patient;
    $scales = new Scale;
    $patient->name = $request->input('name');
    $scales->sd_abc_1_old = $request->input('sd_abc_1_old');
    $patient->save();

    return redirect('/patients')->with('success', 'Paciente creado.');

}
```

I try this code but get error.

```
 DB::transaction(function() use ($patient, $scales) {
   $patient = $patient->save(); //Patient Exists First
   Patient::find($patient->id)->scales()->save($scales)
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
    $this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required',
    'birth' => 'required',
    'nacionality' => 'required',
    'adress' => 'required',
    'phone' => 'required',
    'living_method' => 'required',
    'responsable' => 'required',
]);

//Create Patient
    $patient = Patient::create([
    'name' => $request->input('name'),
 ]);
 $scale = Scale::create([
 'patient_id' => $patient->id, 
'sd_abc_1_old' => $request->sd_abc_1_old,
 ]);



 return redirect('/patients')->with('success', 'Paciente creado.');
}
```

Comment: This does not protect you against DB exceptions. The second DB insert on `Scale` could fail and now the first DB insert of `Patient` will be an orphaned record.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'birth' => 'required',
        'nacionality' => 'required',
        'adress' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'living_method' => 'required',
        'responsable' => 'required',
    ]);

    //Create Patient
    $patient = new Patient;
    $patient->name = $request->name;
    $patient->save();
    $patient->scale()->create(['patient_id' => $patient->id, 'sd_abc_1_old' => $request->sd_abc_1_old]);
);

return redirect('/patients')->with('success', 'Paciente creado.');
}
```

If the model uses a `hasOne()` relation like you said then the code show work, with a bit of modification of course.

Answer (score -1):

First create and store base model and referencing it save related model

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'birth' => 'required',
        'nacionality' => 'required',
        'adress' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'living_method' => 'required',
        'responsable' => 'required',
    ]);

    //Create Patient
    $patient = new Patient;
    $patient->name = $request->input('name');
    $patient->save();

    $scales = new Scale;
    $scales->sd_abc_1_old = $request->input('sd_abc_1_old');

    $patient->scales()->save($scales);


    return redirect('/patients')->with('success', 'Paciente creado.');

}
```

Comment: It's straight forward. First create and store base model and referencing it save related model

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models